# Error using dynamic variable specification in R survey function svychisq()

Tags: r, survey, chi-squared

I am using the functions in the R `survey`-library, and per [this example on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25007913/125085), I use `bquote()` and `as.name()` to dynamically construct the formula for specifying the variables.

This works fine for `svytable()`, but not for `svychisq()`. For example:

```
library(survey)

data(api)
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

colvar <- 'sch.wide'
rowvar <- 'awards' 

svytable(bquote(~.(as.name(rowvar)) + .(as.name(colvar)) ), dstrat)

      sch.wide
awards      No     Yes
   No  1065.69 1170.74
   Yes    0.00 3957.57

svychisq(bquote(~.(as.name(rowvar)) + .(as.name(colvar)) ), dstrat)
```

**Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute**

Can I make this dynamic variable-specification more robust, so that `svychisq()` picks up the correct terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `svychisq` doesn't evaluate it's first parameter in the same way that `svydesign` does. The `bquote` is returning a language object that's not being evaluated into a proper formula. You can call the eval yourself to overcome that issue.

```
svychisq(eval(bquote(~.(as.name(rowvar)) + .(as.name(colvar)) )), dstrat)
#         Pearson's X^2: Rao & Scott adjustment
# 
# data:  svychisq(eval(bquote(~.(as.name(rowvar)) + .(as.name(colvar)))),     dstrat)
# F = 77.2769, ndf = 1, ddf = 197, p-value = 7.364e-16
```

you could also consider building the formula as a string

```
svychisq(as.formula(paste("~", rowvar, "+", colvar)), dstrat)
```

Comment: Thank you for the second option. I was just to about to post a "competing answer", since I thought it was more intuitive.