# svytable and svychisq not recognizing homemade function variables, running RStudio Version 0.99.467 running R 3.2.3 Windows 64 bit

Tags: r

I am trying to build a function in R that will allow me to generate weighted tables of named variables within in a data frame using the R survey package by Thomas Lumley. I think I am running into errors because the svytable and svychisq functions in the survey package are not recognizing the arguments in my homemade function as the names of the desired variables from my data frame I want analyzed.

I had tried to utilize the example given here to develop a solution: 
[lapply with anonymous function call to svytable results in object 'x' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007470/lapply-with-anonymous-function-call-to-svytable-results-in-object-x-not-found)

I also took a look at this post when trying to troubleshoot svychisq: [Error using dynamic variable specification in R survey function svychisq()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918065/error-using-dynamic-variable-specification-in-r-survey-function-svychisq)

None of the suggestions from these posts have worked for me to date. I would very much appreciate if people could look through my code and give feedback for what I could try to generate a function that prints 1. a weighted table of totals 2. the results of running a chi square analysis on that weighted table.

Here is my data/code to date:

```
#data to make the code reproducible 
    independent <-   c(2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1)

    dependent <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,98,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,5,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,5,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,4,3,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1)'

    weight <- c(2937,9389,7918,3851,8560,7433,6577,4507,5601,1358,7274,4507,5160,2429,618,4938,3734,5177,3683,3988,3534,2364,1979,5879,5131,6119,4321,4425,1302,3563,5133,10947,2183,3988,6607,5637,4507,5598,3086,6341,2553,6040,15050,809,5056,5709,2557,3734,1136,2596,7029,4507,2099,1296,4103,4030,4944,3940,4358,5598,1794,4636,6130,6119,431,4944,8361,5732,2602,6117,3719,2727,1406,6023,15050,3870,6808,3957,4507,3827,3658,7600,4244,4507,1850,4358,3770,4103,4927,4801,4012,2364,5547,4381,4103,4444,1427,5575,4656,3708,2865,4447,5709,477,2617,6232,3160,2745,3103,1604,2925,3950,1679,1341,7420,7600,1655,6307,4041,3882,5058,6412,4332,3415,7913,4330,5604,4027,305,4933,4635,1224,4464,8988,4664,1143,882,4061,6142,5763,9811,882,580,780,6973,1752,4263,3809,3440,4447,4740,443,3438,4076,3948,3438,2429,3582,4397,4283,4399,2028,758,15944,3593,4430,4159,4292,5976,3619,18834,2301,4485,942,5861,4284,2102,2102,8503,942,4747,8503,4358,4348,1794,4783,1899,373,5811,2183,5575,4702,4466,4653,3216,4553,7523,2606,2396,3216)

    psu <- c(108,167,224,185,167,151,294,187,274,111,161,187,286,179,228,145,108,248,240,267,253,109,179,240,228,172,278,165,129,153,271,161,141,267,243,278,187,168,108,250,179,194,210,278,114,240,189,108,287,189,154,187,141,251,108,108,187,142,145,168,143,253,172,172,178,187,165,187,267,172,177,165,167,186,210,107,168,108,187,167,186,273,187,187,179,145,174,108,115,115,215,109,253,120,108,240,123,150,115,115,278,174,240,142,109,159,187,185,176,140,220,166,129,129,240,273,111,161,141,141,121,115,120,175,168,472,472,142,142,145,147,145,150,132,186,166,166,169,161,169,163,166,166,166,163,179,178,176,177,174,180,178,171,180,171,171,179,173,192,192,157,154,151,160,154,142,186,186,163,171,160,141,142,143,143,148,141,141,143,143,150,143,145,147,143,141,141,142,148,141,150,141,148,148,136,134,140,136,136,136)

    #make the data frame for reproducible example
    dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(independent,dependent,weight,psu))
    dat$independent <- factor(dat$independent, levels=c("1", "2"))
    dat$dependent <- factor(dat$dependent, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "98"))
    str(dat) 

    #Function to print svytables + chi square statistic

    library(survey) #opens the survey package in R

    x <- independent 
    y <- dependent

    cstbl <- function(x,y) {
        dat_w <- svydesign(id=~psu, weights=~weight, data=dat)
        tbl <- svytable(bquote(~.(as.name(y)+as.name(x))), dat_w) #should make table
        chi <- svychisq(as.formula(paste("~", x, "+", y)), dat_w) #should give test stat
        final <- list(tbl, chi)
        return(final) #should return table + chi square test stat 
    }

    cstbl(x,y)
```

This throws the error:  "Error in as.name(y) + as.name(x) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator"

I get the same error if I replace the third line of the function with 
`tbl <- svytable(~y+x, dat_w)`

Your guidance and patience are much appreciated, as I am new to programming.

Comment: There are many similar questions on SO and the answer usually involves the `as.formula` function. Do a search with that function name.