# Sapply with LM returns a Call function that Stargazer can't use. How do I change that?

Tags: r, sapply, stargazer

I'm trying to use sapply to regress on a number of outcome variables. The sapply function works and returns the linear models properly, BUT the Call returns '''Call:
FUN(formula = X[[i]], data = ..1)'''. I believe that this is the reason that I cannot then plug the sapply output into Stargazer without getting this error:

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

I have compare the output of the sapply variable with a manual plug in for the first outcome variable. The results are the same but Stargazer won't work with the sapply version.

This works:

```
normal_approach <- lm(y_1~x, data = df)
stargazer(normal_approach, type = 'text')
```

This does not:

```
test_col <- c("y_1") #I have more variables but troubleshooting so removed them
names(n) <- names(test_col)

forms <- paste(test_col, '~x')
sapp_approach <- sapply(forms, lm, data = df, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)

sapply_version <- sapp_approach$`y_1~x' #confirmed that this variable is correct
stargazer(sapply_version, type = 'text')

% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

The Call function in the sapply approach is the problem, I think.

```
Call: FUN(formula = X[[i]], data = ..1)
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is not that easy to tell for sure, but you could try an approach similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007470/lapply-with-anonymous-function-call-to-svytable-results-in-object-x-not-found/25007913#25007913

Comment: That is because you are passing a list that contains the model object to stargazer, instead of the model object directly.. In your particuar example, if you do stargazer(sapply_version[[1]], type = 'text') it should work. For more models you can do lapply(sapply_version, stargazer, type = "text")

Comment: @TomasCapretto I've tried that before posting. It doesn't work. I'm fairly certain the issue is the Call function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stargazer` has issues while displaying the output for list of models. A "hack" would be to get data in long format before creating the model.

Since there is no data shared here's a way using `mtcars` dataset keeping only the first 3 columns from it. In place of your `x` column I am using `disp` here.

```
library(stargazer)

df <- mtcars[1:3]
df1 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -disp)
list_df <- split(df1, df1$name)

lm_model_list <- lapply(list_df, function(x) lm(disp~value, x))
```

Output -

```
#For one model
stargazer(lm_model_list$cyl, type = 'text')


===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                               disp            
-----------------------------------------------
value                        62.599***         
                              (5.469)          
                                               
Constant                    -156.609***        
                             (35.181)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    32             
R2                             0.814           
Adjusted R2                    0.807           
Residual Std. Error      54.385 (df = 30)      
F Statistic           130.999*** (df = 1; 30)  
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01


#For list of models
stargazer(lm_model_list, type = 'text')


==========================================================
                                  Dependent variable:     
                              ----------------------------
                                          disp            
                                   (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------------------------------
value                           62.599***     -17.429***  
                                 (5.469)        (1.993)   
                                                          
Constant                       -156.609***    580.884***  
                                 (35.181)      (41.740)   
                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------
Observations                        32            32      
R2                                0.814          0.718    
Adjusted R2                       0.807          0.709    
Residual Std. Error (df = 30)     54.385        66.863    
F Statistic (df = 1; 30)        130.999***     76.513***  
==========================================================
Note:                          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: AMAZING! Yes, this works. It does it beautifully. Thank you so much.